# Does an expression exist such that...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Can you prove or disprove the existence of an expression P, such that

$Z=6ab+a+b-P$

Makes Z expressible in the form;

$Z=6xy\pm x \pm y$ 
for all a and b
where $a,b,x,y∈N $

**Finding an example of P would act as sufficient proof.**

**$P$ cannot involve the variables $a$ and $b$**

Clarification:

Assume instead we are using the expression $2K+1$

Hence;

$N=2k+1-P$

In this scenario, letting P= 2r would suffice, since then ;

$N=2(k-r)+1$

Hence N would be of the form $2Q+1$

Comment: It shouldn't be $P(x)$ here since there is no $x$ in either formula for $Z$. Could you re-write what you are looking for, without the $P(x)$, or with a new version of it so one can tell what the $P$ should depend on? Also you should have a product of two terms equal to a third, if you are to get "factors".

Comment: I'm not sure how I could do that since P(x) is meant to represent ANY expression with however many variables you want.

Comment: If so I'd just suggest using $P$ rather than mentioning its variables, and saying verbally in the question that it is to depend on whatever variables are needed. Still it isn't clear (to me anyway) what $P$ is supposed to be doing, between the two things. Are you subtracting it from one and want the result to have the other as a factor?

Comment: @user129967, I think the question could do with a major rewrite. I am even willing to help you rewrite it, if you're willing to discuss here in the comments.

Comment: Yes ok that would certainly help. Is the question itself too long or is it just unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have rewritten this, as the previous version was a little rushed.*

If zero may appear then, for any expression $P$,

$6ab + a + b - P = 6(6ab + a + b - P)(0) + (6ab + a + b - P) + (0)$

Otherwise suppose we have non-zero expression $P$ such that for any non-zero $a$, $b$

$(6ab + a + b) - P = (6xy + x + y)$ for some non-zero $x$, $y$

then

$(36ab + 6a + 6b) - 6P = (36xy + 6x + 6y)$

$(6a+1)(6b+1) - 6P = (6x+1)(6y+1)$

So $6P$, when subtracted from *any* number expressible as the product of two numbers $\equiv 1 \mod 6$, neither equal to 1, (i.e. a composite number $\equiv 1 \mod 6$*) gives another such number. Hence we can show this is impossible if for any $P$ there exists a prime number $n$, and a composite number $m \equiv 1 \mod 6$, such that $n + 6P = m$.

* Note that since negative numbers are allowed every composite $\equiv 1 \mod 6$ can be expressed with factors $\equiv 1 \mod 6$ e.g. $55 = -5 * -11 = (6(-1)+1)*(6(-2)+1)$

Take any prime number $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$ and consider the sequence $p$, $p+6P$, $p+12P$, ..., $p+6(p-1)P$, $p+6pP$. Now $p$ is prime, and $p+6pP$ is composite ($P$ non-zero) , so somewhere the sequence switches from prime to composite, and we have a composite $\equiv 1 \mod 6$ that is $6P$ greater than a prime.

Hence there is no such $P$.

Comment: You cannot assume either of M or N are prime as both are expressible as the products of two numbers of the form $1mod6$

Comment: I'm not assuming either is prime. I'm showing for a composite n, m is not always composite.

Comment: Can you prove the same result for when $Z=6ab+a-b$

Comment: If you want $(6ab + a - b) - P = (6xy + x - y)$ then the argument is basically identical, but with numbers $\equiv -1 \mod 6$. But with $(6ab + a + b) - P = (6xy + x - y)$ the method breaks down since one number is $\equiv 1 \mod 6$ the other $\equiv -1 \mod 6$, the difference $6P+2$, and the sequence argument is inapplicable. But I still think the negative result would hold. I'm waiting to see if http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696052/can-there-be-n-such-that-p-equiv-a-mod-n-a-prime-rightarrow-pn-also-pr gets an answer.